# Toast not appearing on the screen

Tags: android, toast

For 5000ms I m showing a dialog box After dismissal of my dialog-box, toast should appear but its not, why I m not getting this?how can I do this?

Help is always appreciated..!

```
 signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //  showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                    try {
                         while(counter<1){
                                showmsg(0);
                                Thread.sleep(5000);


                         }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });


}

 @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        ++counter;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        if(counter==1){
        dialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        }  
        else{

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        } 
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
} 


 public void showmsg(int actionsToBePerformedOnScreen) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = actionsToBePerformedOnScreen;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:

                showDialog(0);

                break;

            case 1:
                // clear all images in the list
                removeDialog(0);
                break;


            }

        };
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to show your Toast in `onCreateDialog` method and it's conditioned on `counter!=1`. `onCreateDialog` is not called when you show dialog but only when you create it. It's only called once so Toast never appear.

---

I believe that you are trying to run the thread, show progress when it's running and dismiss it and show Toast when it's complete. If that's the case, much simpler and correct way to achieve your goal is to use `AsyncTask`. Read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Gitelman,  Thanks for ur suggestion .I m new to android and what should I do to solve this?

Comment: You should use/override onShowDialog instead.

Comment: For one thing I don't see where you are dismissing dialog. I will update answer with some suggestion.

Comment: Updated answer with reference to AsyncTask.